# I want more explication for single instance in class runtime [JAVA]

Tags: java, class, runtime, single-instance

in java doc
class Runtime : Every Java application has a single instance of class Runtime

What's single instance in class Runtime

Comment: take a look at this https://medium.com/@govinda_raj/runtime-class-in-java-43c730dbb876

Comment: it means that when you call `Runtime.getRuntime()`, you will always have the same [Runtime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html) object instance for the same Java application running.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40486720/what-is-a-runtime-class-in-java check this too

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels It looks to me like this question is asking "what is [the Runtime class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html)", not "what is a runtime class".

Comment: question re-opened